# c# - How to set label for only major tick marks using custom label

Tags: c#

I have major tick mark and minor tick marks in a chart. I'm using custom label of the Axis class to add a label for each data point in the chart series. But I need to display the label at only the major tick marks unlike what is shown in the attached screenshot. Is there a way I can do this?
This is the code:

```
foreach (DataPoint dp in series.Points)
{
   if (DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue).Day == 1 || DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue).Day == 2)
   {      
       chartArea.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(dp.XValue - 0.5, dp.XValue + 0.5, (DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue)).ToString(monthFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) + " " + (DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue)).Year);
   }
   else
   {
      chartArea.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(dp.XValue - 0.5, dp.XValue + 0.5, (DateTime.FromOADate(dp.XValue)).ToString("%d", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
   }                    
}
```

[image]